# Dynamics CRM: using Xrm.Page library in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using Eclipse as JavaScript IDE.

I would like to setup Xrm.Page library in this environment (for code completion and assistance).

I couldn't find any separate library files and any tools for that, just for Visual Studio.
Is there a solution for using it in Eclipse?

Comment: Any reason you're fighting drinking the Kool-Aid?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse as IDE for other programming languages so I don't want to change IDE just because of Xrm.Page library. And also because VS is not free + it would take some time to feel comfortable with the new environment.

Comment: The expression versions of VS are free, which is all you'd need in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install a free copy of Visual Studio Express.
2. Install the VS extension from `\sdk\templates\xrm.pagescriptprojecttemplate`
3. Create a VS solution from the XrmPageScript template.
4. From the new solution copy of the file `\Scripts\XrmPageTemplate.js`

Now you can bring the XrmPageTemplate.js file into Eclipse and develop with code-completion, etc.

**UPDATED DEC 02 2013**

After looking at your comments I did some further investigation. Eclipse, unlike Visual Studio, does not support code completion from JavaScript source in a reliable manner. In most cases it requires a custom plugin be created to support auto completion.

Quoting from [Add External JS Libraries to Eclipse JSDT-driven Projects](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/add-external-js-libraries-to-eclipse-jsdt-driven-projects.html#fbid=z_vNKTdNlIV):

> Resources which are added to the Build Path can theoretically be made
>   available for Content Assist. That's an important distinction because
>   ensuring that the file is scanned does not guarantee that it will be
>   correctly converted into a usable object model. That's because, in
>   order for some JDT-based functionality to work correctly, class type
>   information must be inferred in many cases. Eclipse examines the
>   JavaScript Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) in order to generate "virtual"
>   class information. And while the unique conventions of the various
>   JavaScript Toolkits such as Dodo, jQuery, and Prototype can be handled
>   to some extent, at this point it's still provisional.
>
> Some of the makers of popular JS libraries have taken a proactive role
>   in exposing their object model to Eclipse via a plugin.

Since the only supported development environment for Dynamics CRM is Visual Studio is not likely to see a custom plugin be released to support `Xrm.Page`.

Comment: I followed all the steps and I have `XrmPageTemplate.js`. I added this script as a library to project in Eclipse but the code-completion is not there.

Comment: It's just a JavaScript file, so assuming Eclipse supports autocomplete for JavaScript, it should work. Do you have to do additional configuration for Eclipse to autocomplete JavaScript? I'm not an Eclipse user - my answer was only to get you the JavaScript source to Xrm.Page, so you could avoid having to use Visual Studio.

Comment: In Eclipse, I created a User Library containing that file and added it to project as usual. I think `XrmPageTemplate.js` does not contain the objects I'm looking for.

Comment: What objects are you looking for? I look in the file and I see all the Xrm.Page objects.